# Killing child process in node.js/electron

Tags: node.js, electron

I am opening a child process in node.js to start an RTSP stream using VLC. I then want to kill the process once a command has been sent from the electron application.

Here is the code I  have written. Is there anything I am doing wrong because the child process doesn't get killed even though the code is run through. I have checked that cam is not undefined, it actually enters that code block.

```
const { dialog, ipcMain, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const {url} = require('url');
var net = require('net');
var spawn = require('child_process').exec;
var cam;

class streamHandler { 
    constructor(){
        this.sendAndReceiveMessageListener();
    }

    sendAndReceiveMessageListener(){
        ipcMain.on('http-request', (event)=>{
            let message = "Starting the video stream";
            cam = spawn('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe" --qt-start-minimized  rtsp://192.168.0.75/live --sout "#transcode{acodec=vorb, vcodec=theo}:standard{access=http, mux=ogg, dst=localhost:8090/}"', function(error, stdout, stderr){});
            event.sender.send('http-response', (message));
        });

        ipcMain.on('http-end-stream-request', (event)=>{
            let message = "Video stream ended.";
            if (typeof cam !== 'undefined' && cam !== null){
                cam.kill('');
            }

            event.sender.send('http-end-stream-response', (message));

        });
    }

    spawnVLC(){
        console.log()
    }
}

module.exports = new streamHandler();
```

Comment: "even though the code is run through". Just to make sure that I understand, have you verified that `cam.kill('')` is being called? Second, why are you passing in an empty string into `kill`? Just call `cam.kill()`

Comment: Hi, I tried using cam.kill(), still doesn't work. I have verified that cam.kill() does get called it just doesn't do anything and I am trying to understand why. I have tried all the different string arguments that the kill() function can take as well, without any luck.

Comment: When you spawn the process, can you also add handlers for the `close` event and the `error` event and see if any of those handlers gets hit when calling `kill()`?

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons this might be happening is because the child process that you spawned (`RTSP stream using VLC` - let's called this child process 'A'), is creating other child processes ('B', 'C' etc.) which will not be killed when you try to kill child process 'A'.

> When the child thread finishes executing and deletes, the grandchild thread becomes the zombie process, and **process.kill() cannot delete it.**

You can use the following approach:

Spawn the child process in detached mode so that you can kill all the child processes.

```
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    var child = spawn('my-command', {detached: true});
    process.kill(-child.pid);
```

Please note `-` before `pid`. This converts a `pid` to a group of `pids` for process `kill()` method.

*Related links:*

[How to] https://azimi.me/2014/12/31/kill-child_process-node-js.html

[Related Issue] https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1389

[Documentation] https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_kill_signal